# Spring boot autoconfigure EMS Tibco Queue to send a message

Tags: spring-boot, jms, config, tibco-ems

I am trying to send a message to a Tibco Queue using Spring Boot, and I have achieved it using [`JMSComponent`](http://camel.apache.org/maven/current/camel-jms/apidocs/org/apache/camel/component/jms/JmsComponent.html). It does not use Spring Boot's built-in autoconfiguration files.

Can anyone please provide an example that uses `spring.jms.jndi-name-<JNDI name>` in `application.properties` file, autoconfigures Spring Boot, and sends a message?

I could see lot of examples available for configuring ActiveMQ Queue in Spring Boot but none for configuring Tibco Queue or using [`JMSAutoconfiguration`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jms/JmsAutoConfiguration.html).

Answer (score 3):

Here's the relationship of these parameters.
An example for ActiveMQ:

```
 jndiContextFactory: org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory
 jndiProviderUrl: tcp://localhost:61616
 jndiCFName: ConnectionFactory
```

and for TIBCO EMS:

```
 jndiContextFactory: com.tibco.tibjms.naming.TibjmsInitialContextFactory
 jndiProviderUrl: tibjmsnaming://localhost:51515
 jndiCFName: cf1
```

The connection factory name is the name of a pre-configured connection factory. By default, ActiveMQ has one named, "ConnectionFactory". With TIBCO EMS, before version 8, I believe, there was a default one named "GenericConnectionFactory". With EMS 8.x you need to create all factories yourself, using 'tibemsadmin':

```
create factory cf1 generic url=tcp://localhost:7222
```